# How to get browser console logs when using Browser library in Robotframework

Tags: selenium, robotframework, playwright, playwright-python

I'm using Robotframework and Browser library to automate some tasks on the web. I used to use Selenium, and with selenium there is a way to get the logs, for example in the case of a failure:

```
driver = webdriver.Remote()
logs = driver.get_log('browser')
```

I've been struggling to find a way to do the same exact thing using Playwright's Browser library. Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Certainly. You can use the [page.on('console')](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-page#page-event-console) event to log what appears in the DevTools console. Here's an example of using [debug](https://www.npmjs.com/package/debug) library to do so.

Make sure to `export DEBUG=playwright:console` or you won't see anything.
Here's how to do it in JS:

```js
const playwright = require('playwright');
const debugConsole = require('debug')('playwright:console');

(async () => {
    const browser = await playwright.chromium.launch({ headless: false });
    const context = await browser.newContext();
    const page = await context.newPage();

    await page.on('console', (msg) => {
        if (msg && msg.text) {
          if (typeof msg.text === 'function') {
            debugConsole('PAGE LOG:', msg.text());
          } else {
            debugConsole('PAGE LOG:', msg.text);
          }
        } else {
          debugConsole('PAGE LOG:', msg);
        }
    });

    await page.goto('https://example.com', { waitUntil: 'networkidle' });

})();
```

And in python:

```py
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright

def print_args(msg):
    for arg in msg.args:
        print(arg.json_value())

with sync_playwright() as p:
    browser = p.chromium.launch()
    page = browser.new_page()
    page.on("console", print_args)
    page.goto("https://abrahamjuliot.github.io/creepjs/", wait_until="networkidle")
    page.wait_for_timeout(5000)
    browser.close()
```

If you are looking for more system-level stuff, there is also a [dumpio](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-browsertype#browser-type-launch) launch parameter that you can set, which will cause Playwright to provide verbose logs on the actual launch of browser executable.

Comment: Thank you! Your code is in JS, right? How can I do it in Python? :)

Comment: @wikofad877 Updated my answer to include in Python sample :)

Comment: Thank you very much. Does it work only on Chromium?